# winapi c++ GetAncestor/GetParent

Tags: c++, winapi

I try to make `bmp` to `ico` converter. I have problem with `GetParent`/`GetAncestor` function. Here are some fragments of my code:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
   HWND hWndAbout;
   switch (message)
      {  
          /* ... */

          hWndAbout = CreateDialog(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(KONWERTER_DIALOG_ABOUT), hwnd, AboutDlgProc);
          ShowWindow(hWndAbout, SW_SHOW);

       }
}
```

This was a part from where the jurney begins to the other part:

```
BOOL CALLBACK AboutDlgProc(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:  
    break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        HWND hwndParent;
        HDC hDCParent;
        hwndParent = GetAncestor(hDlg, GA_PARENT); //hwndParent = GetParent(hDlg); //hwndParent = GetRealParent(hDlg);
        hDCParent = GetDC(hwndParent);  
        hDC1 = GetDC(hDlg);
        if (g_Checked1)StretchBlt(hDC1, 0, 0, 16, 16, hDCParent, 0, 0, 600, 600, SRCCOPY);
        if (g_Checked2)StretchBlt(hDC1, 0, 0, 32, 32, hDCParent, 0, 0, 600, 600, SRCCOPY);
        if (g_Checked3)StretchBlt(hDC1, 0, 0, 64, 64, hDCParent, 0, 0, 600, 600, SRCCOPY);
        create_icon(hDlg);
        ReleaseDC(hDlg, hDC1);
        ReleaseDC(hwndParent, hDCParent);
    break;

    /* ... */
    }
}
```

I want to `hwndParent` be the `hwnd` handler, but it becomes a handler to desktop.

Whats wrong?

[How I visualize my idea?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bb6WU.png)

As you can see my `StreachBlt` draws part of the desktop, not my lovely face. I already tried using `GetParent` which gave same result. Thank you for help.

Comment: Try using `GetParent()` instead of `GetAncestor()`.

Comment: As you can see I already tried:
     hwndParent = GetAncestor(hDlg, GA_PARENT); //hwndParent = GetParent(hDlg); //hwndParent = GetRealParent(hDlg);

Comment: In order to paint the dialog you need the window handle of the dialog, not of the dialogs parent or owner. And the correct handling of `WM_PAINT` involves calling `BeginPaint` and `EndPaint`, at the minimum. Unless you're forwarding to code that does that.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.- You're absolutely correct about begin and end paint, but take another look at those `StretchBlt` calls. `hdcDest` is the dialog's DC, `hdcSrc` is the (incorrect) parent DC. The OP is painting into the correct DC, but grabbing the data from the wrong location. piotrus1444 - Why copy it off the screen at all? Just create a shared DC to hold the image data and use that to paint to both locations. You obviously have that image stored _somewhere_ to preserve it across repaint cycles.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for help. Some advices helped me to understand my problem. I resolved it by changing CreateDialog() to CreateDialogParam() and I passed the parent handler using lParam parameter:

```
hWndAbout = CreateDialogParam(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(KONWERTER_DIALOG_ABOUT), hwnd, AboutDlgProc, (LPARAM)hwnd);
                ShowWindow(hWndAbout, SW_SHOW);
```

and in child window I used WM_INITDIALOG get the handler:

```
case WM_INITDIALOG:
    hwndParent = (HWND)lParam;
break;
```